Plotting curves with variable parameters
I have a collection of curves of the following type:

It has a description parameter (y) and another variable parameter (x) that allows to changing the horizontal position of the curve
I would like to draw some of them using a loop like this:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox,calc,decorations.markings,external,math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\xlim{3}
        \def\ylim{3}
        \def\step{0.5}
        
        \foreach \x in {-\xlim,-\xlim+\step,...,\xlim}
        {
            \draw[Cyan,thin] plot[domain=-\ylim:\ylim, variable=\y, smooth] ({\x + cos(\y r)},{\y});
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But I get the following errors:

Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
-halt-on-e
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{tikzpicture}
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\end{tikzpicture}

Could someone help me on what I'm doing wrong?

Unless you load xcolor with a suitable option, Cyan (with capital c) isn't defined.

BTW, it's worth relying on \imath and \jmath for the vectors “i” and “j”.

Use the parse=true option to tell tikz that it should evaluate the expressions in your list:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\xlim{3}
        \def\ylim{3}
        \def\step{0.5}
        
        \foreach \x [parse=true] in {-\xlim,-\xlim+\step,...,\xlim}
        {
            \draw[cyan,thin] plot[domain=-\ylim:\ylim, variable=\y, smooth] ({\x + cos(\y r)},{\y});
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


